# jQuery - obtain attribute from element when hover

Tags: jquery

Attempting to apply `.hover` to a class that shows a div based on a dynamic ID.  For example:

**HTML**

```
<div id="parent_one">
    <div class="touch" id="one">Touch me!</div>
    <div id="t_one"></div>
</div>
<div id="parent_two">
    <div class="touch" id="two">Touch me!</div>
    <div id="t_two"></div>
</div>
```

**jQuery**

```
$('.touch').hover(
    function(){
        var id = $(this).attr('id');
        var value = '#t_' + id;
        $(value).fadeIn(800);
    },
    function(){
        var id = $(this).attr('id');
        var value = '#t_' + id;
        $(value).delay(1500).fadeOut(800);
    }
);
```

I have a feeling my mistake is in the use of `$(this)` but can't nail it down.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This:

```
var value = 't_' + id;
```

Needs to include `#`:

```
var value = '#t_' + id;
```

Otherwise you are just selecting for an element with the tag `t_one`, which is not an existing tag name.

However using ids for this is pretty ugly. If you have consistent HTML like this, why not use a class structure like this:

```
<div>
  <div class="touch-handle">Touch me!</div>
  <div class="content"></div>
</div>
```

with JS like this:

```
$('.touch-handle').hover(
  function(){
    $(this).next('.content').fadeIn(800);
  },
  function(){
    $(this).next('.content').delay(1500).fadeOut(800);
  }
);
```

Comment: Typo, updated.  Still doesn't work in my model of the code.  Here's a fiddle. http://jsfiddle.net/7dcuh/8/

Comment: @Plummer That seems to work fine, you just don't have anything inside the divs so they remain invisible. http://jsfiddle.net/7dcuh/9/

Comment: Knew nothing of `.next`.  Thanks.